# Try on SaveChanges Entity FrameWork 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am using Code First.

execute

```
            try
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (EntityException e)
        {

        }
```

Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

```
            this.Property(t => t.Senha)
            .HasMaxLength(15);
```

I forced a password greater than 15 characters, catch will never execute, why?

Comment: As a side comment, maximum password lengths should be made significantly larger unless you absolutely need the short password. Most hashing methods output identically lengthed results regardless of input and passphrases are great from a security and usability perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs at validating the entity resulting in a [DbEntityValidationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.validation.dbentityvalidationexception%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

So try

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are catching incorrect exception. try this :

```
     try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {

    }
```